# Vaadin Modal Window: How To Get Scrollbars On The Parent View

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm working with Vaadin 7.6.1 and I got a problem with Vaadin's Window component. My window is modal and has a fix size. But if the browser window is resized the window is too large for displaying it completely.

The following image should explain the context:

[image: ImageDialogScrollProblem]

In this case I want the browser to display scrollbars, so the user can still use the whole dialog.

I used the code structure of Vaadin's official dashboard demo and modified it: https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo.

**Edit**: Maybe it's interesting to reproduce the problem. In the Vaadin Sampler you can open the Window, set it to modal, resize it (larger) and finally resize the browser window: http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/structure/window

**Edit2**: This example of JQuery's Dialog demonstrates my requirements: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form
After opening the dialog I can resize the browser window so it's not possible to display the whole dialog. But there are scrollbars so the user can still use it.

Comment: I am not sure if scrolling is possible as you would like to have it but you can make the modal window's content scrollable.

Comment: Can you please provide a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem on github or similar so we can see if any workaround is possible? It may also have something to do with what you do `UI.init()` so unless we have all the info at hand it's difficult to guess.

Comment: I think it's a general problem. Nevertheless: https://github.com/shinchillahh/vaadinWindowResizingProblem
Just start it and resize the browser, so the window is not displayed completely.

Comment: Added a possible workaround which was too small to fit in a comment. Next time please use @username when replying to someone's comment so they get notified, because I almost missed yours :-)

Comment: @Morfic Thank you very much for your hint. Next time I will consider it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the generated sources, it looks like the `body` defines `overflow: hidden;` by default, so no scrollbars show up. A possible workaround (with some inspiration from [here](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=3&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com%20wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=Vaadin%20Theme%20Tips%20and%20Tricks#section-Vaadin%20Theme%20Tips%20and%20Tricks-Implementation%20tips)) is to change it to `overflow: auto;` in your theme.

> If you know it's safe to specify something on the
>
> ```
> body
> ```
>
> element (e.g.the theme will be used only in an app that is the only thing on the page), you can use the
>
> ```
> .v-generated-body
> ```
>
> selector. It will be available only if the application is served directly from the servlet,and not embedded in another page.

Not sure [this](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Adding+a+splash+screen) applies any longer, but it did not work for me until I moved the definition outside the `@mixin` just as explained there:

> Note that Vaadin 7.0 incorrectly does not add the theme name during
>   bootstrap. You must therefore use a rule without the theme name, e.g.
>
> ```
> .v-generated-body .v-app .v-app-loading
> ```
>
> and move it out of the @mixin. You also need to ensure the v-app div has a height using
>
> ```
> .v-app {height:100%;}
> ```

**mytheme.scss**

```
@import "../valo/valo";

// must be outside theme mixin as per https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Adding+a+splash+screen
.v-generated-body {
  // change the overflow from hidden to auto
  overflow: auto;
  // copy the rest as it was
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

@mixin mytheme {
  @include valo;

  // other customizations
}
```

You should be getting something similar to:

[image: Sample]

Comment: A thousand thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @shinchillahh You're welcome. Just make sure you get no _weird behaviour_ with the rest of the app when the window is not visible. You can fiddle around and try to set `overflow:auto;` when the body has also `v-modal-windo-open` to limit the changes just to this specific case. I tried yesterday but it didn't seem to work in my first attempts and I was rather busy, so I abandoned it. Cheers :-)